# Facing XML Parsing Error while creating XULRunner application

Tags: python, xml-parsing, xulrunner

I tried creating an XULRunner app as given in the tutorial - http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/no_wrap/tutorials/pyxulrunner/python_xulrunner_about.html

But when I tried running the app it gave me the following error -

```
XML Parsing Error:  
Location: chrome://pyxpcom_gui_app/content/pyxpcom_gui_app.xul 
Line Number 19, Column 48:
persist="screenX screenY width height">
-----------------------------------------------^
```

I am not getting what went wrong. Content of pyxpcom_gui_app.xul -

```
<window id="pyxpcom_gui_app"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        title="&pyxpcom_gui_app.title;"
        style="width: 700px; height: 500px;"
        script-type="application/x-python"
        persist="screenX screenY width height"> <!-- This is Line Number 19 -->
```

I am on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your code doesn't seem to have any syntax errors, the most likely issue is the `&pyxpcom_gui_app.title;` entity reference (note that the XML parser used by Firefox always points to the end of a tag regardless of the line where it finds an unknown entity). Either you forgot to include the DTD file defining this entity or the address of that DTD file is wrong or it doesn't define an entity named `pyxpcom_gui_app.title`.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, yet unsolved.

If the pyxpcom_gui_app.title entity is correctly specified in your DTD, and your DTD is located as specified in your chrome.manifest, then the problem is in the line script-type="application/x-python" (if you delete this line you'll get the XUL part of the application running). According to the Pyxpcomext list, the problem is related to the 1.9.1 pythonext Windows builds, as documented in:

http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/pyxpcomext/2009-March/000052.html

I've tried out the newest builds but they still won't work. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is the entire file, you need to close the window tag.